# Getting back into PvE

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just had a break from WoW when the PvP season ended and I came back this week. I want to get back into raiding but my lvl 90 Ele Sham has terrible 475 gear. How can I get back into raiding as soon as possible?People say timeless Isle, but without gear the killing of the mobs requires double the effort. Is there no other way of getting my gear up quickly? Without the forming of raids to get old gear?

Comment: http://www.icy-veins.com/elemental-shaman-wow-pve-dps-gear-loot-best-in-slot Just try to get stuff on the list, some are easy to come by by doing dungeons and such.

Comment: Why did I receive a down vote for a legit question?

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote was for, but it may have been for saying you were told about the timeless isle but the grind for it is huge -- there is so much easy gear there literally just sitting on the ground, the question reads like you want something easier than picking free loot up off of the floor.

Comment: True, but I didn't understand the isle, I was told you have to kill mobs to get your gear. Nobody told me about the chests. :L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the easiest way to push up your current ilvl is to visit the Timeless Isle.

The first thing you should do is collect all the one-time chests. A great guide for this can be found [here](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1328815-In-depth-Timeless-Isle-Hidden-Chest-Guide!). In the unlikely event that this guide does cease to exist, what you really need is the map which is included in the guide and a quick Google will find you that. This should net you a fair amount of gear tokens which can be used to create a piece of 496 ilvl gear for your current specialisation.

Secondly, the island should still be very busy. On a moderately populated server, you will still get large groups of players roaming the island looking for rare elites. Killing these also have a chance of dropping the gear tokens that the chests dropped. You can actually trade the tokens between other players who killed the same rare as you, so you might be able to bargain with people if they get the token that you need.

If you see any groups fighting any of the four celestials, tag it for another chance at some loot. If you have extra loot roll tokens, use one on this. Older world bosses are still killed and are still worth killing. You might want to try openraid.eu (or the US equivalent) to find groups for these if they are hard to come by on your server.

There are a few one off quests on the island which will also give you a token or two. Try completing these whilst opening treasure chests and chasing rare elites.

A fairly rare item named Burden of Eternity can drop on the isle. These can be combined with a gear token and this will produce an ilvl 535 "Timeless" piece of gear. You do get one guaranteed Burden of Eternity from one of the chests (Blazing Chest [7] on the map).

Apart from that, if you have other level 90 characters, you can repeat the chest process on them and send these tokens to your main as they are Bind on Account.

It is worth doing a Heroic Scenario a day for a chance at ilvl 516 gear, including weapons.

You will need 496 ilvl to queue up for Siege of Orgrimmar LFR.

Hopefully that starts you on your way back to PVE! Enjoy!

Comment: I recently did the first wing of Siege of Orgrimmar in LFR without having finished Throne of the Thunder King. All I needed was to get to 496 ilvl.

Comment: I stand corrected. That must only apply per raid (e.g. you can't do the final wing of SoO without first doing the 1st, 2nd and 3rd in that order). I'll edit my answer, thanks.

Comment: Brilliant post thanks! One question, I noticed that the chests are BOA does that mean that I can send it between servers or just one server? Does it work the same way as heirlooms?

Comment: It works the same way as heirlooms. Currently that means one server only, although you can go cross faction.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently geared up my Balance Druid from scratch (new level 90) to ilvl 510 in less than 3 days. I'll list the complete steps below in case it's useful to someone. You can jump to step 4 since you're already at ilvl 475:

1. Do scenario 'Arena of Annihilation' for the first time and get ilvl 450 weapon. (10-15 minutes)
2. Do random scenario and 5-man dungeons, each 1-2 times per day, to get ilvl 463 armors and collect Justice Points/Valor Points to weekly limit. (4-6 hours total)
3. If you have crafting profession for your class, you can craft the ilvl 476 PvP armors to fill those slots that you didn't get any 463 armors. If you don't, you can buy them on the AH, they're very cheap now as in patch 5.4.
4. Go to Timeless Isle, do the basic 'Talk to X' quests and open all chests within your reach along the way, you'll get at least 3-4 timeless ilvl 496 gears and some Timeless Coin. (<1 hour)
5. Buy a stack of Golden Glider and use them to grab the Blazing Chest which has a guaranteed loot of Burden of Eternity. (10-15 minutes)
6. Put on the timeless armors and use the Burden of Eternity to upgrade the slot that have the most itemization value to ilvl 535, which is Chest or Leggings. This will effectively raise your combat ability to do the quests on the isle.
7. Do dailies and random grinding on the Timeless Isle until you get 50 Lesser Charm of Good Fortune. If there are people attacking elite mobs you can hitchhike to get a chance of loot. Now you should have 10k+ timeless coins, go to the cave and gamble with all the coins. You'll get another at least 3-4 timeless gears from this process and if you're lucky you'll get 1-2 Burden of Eternity's. Again, apply the Burdens to the slots with high itemization value. (2-8 hours depending on your class, spec and gear)
8. Now your ilvl should be over 480. If not, go to the Valor Quartermaster in Niuzao Temple to buy some 489 JP gears. (Note the name is VP vendor but he sells JP gears.)
9. You can queue for Throne of Thunder LFR to get some ilvl 502 loots, as well as do daily Heroic Scenario run to get some ilvl 516 gears. (4-6 hours total)
10. Now your ilvl should be over 496. If not, since you're already Friendly with Shado-Pan (thanks to the ToT run), you can buy ilvl 522 VP gears (preferable necklace, then ring or trinket) from the Shado-Pan Quartermaster in Niuzao temple.
11. If you're still not 496 yet, you can either buy some 496 PvP gears with Honor Point from the Honor Quartermaster on Serpent's Spine, or continue grinding on Timeless Isle.
12. Once your ilvl hits 496, queue for Siege of Orgrimmar LFR. Don't forget to turn in the Lesser Charm of Good Fortune's for Warforged Seals before you enter the raid. Use Wowhead, Atlasloot or AskMrRobot to find out which boss drops the best loot for you and you may want to use the bonus roll.

Good luck!

Comment: Great post NS.X.! I'd recommend using one Warforged Seal on a Celestial kill.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick cheat sheet for ilevel rewards in 5.4:

```
ilevel 496 - all slots except mainhand/offhand,
  Timeless Isle short grind (chests/rares),
  1-2 days
ilevel 496 - mainhand,
  Timeless Isle medium grind (20k timeless coins),
  less than a week
ilevel 535 - all slots except mainhand/offhand/trinkets,
  Timeless Isle long grind.  (Burden of Eternity),
  random, but no more than 5 weeks

ilevel 476 - Mogu'shan Vaults LFR
ilevel 483 - HoF and ToES LFR
ilevel 502 - Throne of Thunder LFR
ilevel 528 - Seige of Orgrimmar LFR
ilevel 540 - Seige of Orgrimmar Flex
```

All of these items may be upgraded for valor to get +8 item levels.

Also, check the auction house for crafted gear.